# How to make onResize work when your widget attach to an Activity

Tags: gwt

How to make someView(like SimpleLayoutPanel)'s onResize work correctly in an Activity. Since it seems we can not trigger the onResize in such place even though every panel implements the RequireResizes.

```
SomeActivity extends AbstractActivity{
    public void start(final AcceptsOneWidget panel, final EventBus eventBus){
        panel.setWidget(someView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `RequiresResize` chain is consistent then the `onResize()` should be called for you on browser resize and on layout change. Why do you want to call it directly?

In your case, the call to `panel.setWidget(someView)` will of course physically and logically attach `someView` to `panel` but it also trigger the `onResize()` method of `panel` that end up calling `onResize()` on its child (i.e., the just attached `someView`).